# How can another file be Included in a Hugo/Markdown page?

Tags: markdown, hugo

Recently the re-development of a web site was given to me. The re-worked site is to be done in [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) and run through the [Hugo static site](https://gohugo.io/) generator.

Is there a way to include other files in a Markdown web page processed through Hugo? If so, how? Unless I've missed something, this isn't addressed in the [Hugo docs](http://gohugo.io/overview/introduction/).

With HTML and some servers (Apache, at least) you can do something like:

```
<html>
<body>
Some content
<!--#include virtual="name_of_first_file_to_include" -->
More content
<!--#include virtual="name_of_second_file_to_include" -->
Still more content
</body>
<html>
```

I've tried creating a template page which puts stuff like "Some content" and "More content" into the template and then the included stuff in my .md file which gets "included" via {{ .Content }} in the template. However, 1) That seems like the wrong way to use a template. 2) I've not figured out a way to bring in more files if I need them.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For content files there are two options:

1. Shortcodes. Powerful and documented.
2. Use `mmark` as the markdown rendering engine with its `include` feature. Rename the content files to "*.mmark". See https://github.com/miekg/mmark

I am the maintainer of Hugo.

Comment: the **include** directive of mmark does some content filtering, am I wrong?

What if I want to include a raw piece of html with scripts inside? (an interactive chart for example )

Comment: I'm not familiar with mmark, but I suspect you can wrap it in a `div`.

But there is a third option: Hugo has a template func named `readFile`, but understand that the result isn't cached in any way, so if you use it from a heavily used template, I suggest you wrap it in `partialCached`.

Comment: *readFile* sounds good :D I haven't noticed that! thank you.

So I need to write a shortcode for including pieces of raw text.

Comment: Documented where, exactly? I went through all the Hugo docs looking for this bud didn't see it. :/

Comment: Note that mmark is deprecated in Hugo, so that rules out option 2.

Comment: honestly I hate to say this but it's VERY unclear how to include something as simple as a `<script>` tag in a markdown/content file. let alone how to use the `{{ }}` template notation stuff in a markdown file. this should be a basic feature and easy to use. been searching for an hour online. IMO the way it should be down is in the markdown you set a key to the name of the html file you want to include and hugo should take care of it.

Answer (score 15):

I have a custom shortcode for rendering my static demo files as code via markdown, it's simple:

layouts/shortcodes/code.html

````
{{ $file := .Get "file" | readFile }}
{{ $lang := .Get "language" }}
{{ (print "```" $lang "\n" $file "\n```") | markdownify }}
````

content/post/some-post.md

```
 {{% code file="/static/some-script.js" language="js" %}}
```

Comment: To use relative file paths: `{{ $filename := (path.Join $.Page.Dir (.Get "file")) }} {{ $file := $filename | readFile }} {{ $file | markdownify }}`.

Comment: In newer Hugo `$.Page.Dir` becomes `$.Page.File.Dir`

Answer (score 4):

A colleague suggested [creating a shortcode](https://gohugo.io/extras/shortcodes#creating-your-own-shortcodes) to help with this. While this isn't quite what I had in mind - it is a more complicated than I would have liked - it's not too bad and I've not found a better way. Thus I've implemented a solution using a [shortcode](https://gohugo.io/extras/shortcodes) and a CSV file. Simple example files are below:

The content file is still (mostly) Markdown and looks something like:

```
+++
date = "2016-09-29"
title = "short_code_test"
type = "pages"
+++

## Short Code test

Test table should appear below:  

{{< display_table_csv "static/test_data.csv" >}}
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Birthday</th>
{{< /test_table_shortcode >}}
```

(Note that the `type = "pages"` just pulls in a template which modifies/overrides the hugo-uno default pages/single.html template to make the output cleaner for purposes of display below.)

layouts/shortcodes/display_table_csv.html:

```
<table>
  <thead>
      {{ .Inner }}
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {{ $url := (index .Params 0) }}
  {{ $sep := "," }}
  {{ range $row_i, $row := getCSV $sep $url }}
  <tr>
    {{ range $col_i, $col := $row }}
    <td>{{ $col }}</td>
    {{ end }}
  </tr>
  {{ end }}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

static/test_data.csv:

```
John, 1940-10-09
Paul, 1942-06-18
George, 1943-02-25
Ringo, 1940-07-07
```

This image shows how things rendered:
[image: Shortcode test screenshot]

The [Data-driven Content page](https://gohugo.io/extras/datadrivencontent/) in the [Hugo docs](https://gohugo.io/overview/introduction/) was helpful also.

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to include markdown files with a shortcode like:

create the file `layouts/shortcodes/include.html` as:

```
{{ $file := .Get 0 }}
{{ (printf "%s%s" .Page.File.Dir $file) | readFile | replaceRE "^---[\\s\\S]+?---" "" | safeHTML }}
```

then include the markdown as:

```
{{% include somefile.md %}}
```

here's a reference link for it: https://roneo.org/en/hugo-include-another-file-with-a-shortcode/