# How do I make a home/landing page in markdown with Hugo?

Tags: hugo

Look, Hugo is for writing static (and blog) sites in markdown. GREAT! **How do I create the home `page` (i.e. not the home `post`)?!**

By home page I mean I want to have some markdown file rendered in my theme at the root: `http://example.com/`, not `http://example.com/home` (I will change themes if necessary, but I'm currently using [hugo-nuo](https://themes.gohugo.io/hugo-nuo/)).

Here's how I'm trying to do it:

add my own `layouts/index.html` (overriding the theme's)

```
{{ define "main" }}
  {{ partial "header.html" . }}
  <section class="main">
    WHERE I WISH I COULD IMPORT home.md OR SOME SUCH, HECK I'D BE ALRIGHT JUST PUTTING MARKDOWN HERE
  </section>
  {{ partial "footer.html" . }}
{{ end }}
```

[This incredibly long thread](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/node-improvements/1593/28) seems to discuss a bunch of issues that've been addressed, but I don't see this answer.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39800156/1449799) says to use shortcodes. I'm willing to do that, but it looks like shortcodes can only be used from within `content` (citation needed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `_index.md` into the folder `content/` and access it, e.g. via `{{ .Content }}`.