# How can you get the full path of a page resource in Hugo?

Tags: hugo, resourcebundle, hugo-shortcode

I have some posts in Hugo with page resources that are SVG files that I want to include inline in the resulting HTML. For example, here's a typical folder structure:

```
content
+-- posts
    +-- somepost
        +-- index.md
        +-- diagram.svg
```

In the post, I'd like to include the content of `diagram.svg` inline as part of the resulting HTML. Reading through [another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539812/how-can-another-file-be-included-in-a-hugo-markdown-page), I created a shortcode to do that that looks like this:

```
{{- readFile (.Get 0) | safeHTML -}}
```

However, this means that I need to provide the full path to the SVG resource, which results in this in my markdown:

```
{{< readsvg "content/posts/somepost/diagram.svg" >}}
```

Ideally, I would like the shortcode to find the page resource so that the markdown can be simplified to:

```
{{< readsvg "diagram.svg" >}}
```

If I use the page resource functions, I can get the resource itself by doing: `{{ $svg := $.Page.Resources.GetMatch (.Get 0) }}` but the resulting file name is relative to the resource bundle while `readFile` needs it to be relative to the top of the project. How can I get the full path of the resource so that I can pass it to `readFile`?

I tried to use `absURL` to do that but this doesn't work as I have custom URLs on posts.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to ruddra for pointing me in the right direction, the full answer that worked was:

```
{{ $svgFile :=  (path.Join (path.Dir .Page.File.Path) (.Get 0)) }}
{{- readFile $svgFile | safeHTML -}}
```

If you want more flexibility in how you specify the resource in the markdown, you can add a resource match to that solution:

```
{{ $svgRes := .Page.Resources.GetMatch (.Get 0) }}
{{ $svgFile :=  (path.Join (path.Dir .Page.File.Path) $svgRes) }}
{{- readFile $svgFile | safeHTML -}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the svg file should be inside `static` directory. But still if you want to put it in same directory as the markdown files, probably you can use [**`.File.Dir`**](https://gohugo.io/variables/files/) in the custom **shortcode**. Like this:

```
{{ $svgFile :=  print (.Page.File.Path) (.Get 0) }}
{{- readFile $svgFile | safeHTML -}}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I'll add the full solution it its own answer.